# sticky footer dosn't work on IE11/10

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, frontend, internet-explorer-10

I have got a page template working fine on chrome. However, on IE 11/10/9 , it has very weird behaviour. My html template is structured as below:-

```css
    @media (min-width:768px){
         /* if remove this line and <!DOCTYPE html>, 
            it will work fine. why????
         */
     .container{width:750px}  
    }
    
    .contentAndFooter {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
      flex-direction: column;
      min-height: 100vh;
      height: 100%; 
    }
    .content {
      -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
      flex: 1 0 auto; 
    }
```

```html
    <body>
     <div class="contentAndFooter" >
       <div class="content">
        <div class='container'>
           <h1>this is my site content</h1>
        </div>
       </div>
       <div class="text-center footer" >
          copyright@bo.chen
       </div>
     </div>
    </body>
```

If I remove `<!DOCTYPE html>` and media query, it would work fine. I really can't figure out why...

cheers,
Bo

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to the head in order to properly use media queries.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the snippet below based on your html markup.

```css
html, body,.contentAndFooter{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding-bottom:50px;
}
.content {
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto -50px;
  background-color:blue;
}
.footer {
  height: 50px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="contentAndFooter" >
      <div class="content">
          <div class='container'>
             <h1>this is my site content</h1>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="text-center footer" >
         copyright@bo.chen
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Actually you can remove contentAndFooter wrapper, it will work as well.